# Honda 90 model 1600 only reving 2500

Tags: honda

We did the engine and now the car rev 2500 only starts and idle nice but not reving over 2500 if I take battery terminal off and start it rev clean to 7000 but after you rev it and try to rev it again it only rev 2500